# Add a black frame around a colorbar

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I have created a heatmap and a colorbar in two separate axes. I want to create a black frame around each of the plots. I've succeeded in ax0 (the heatmap) but for ax1 (the colorbar) it doesn't work. See picture:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 2), columns=list('AB'))
fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10, len(df) / 5.2), gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [15, 15]})
sns.heatmap(df, annot=False, cmap='RdYlGn', cbar_ax=ax1, ax=ax0)
for _, spine in ax1.spines.items():
    spine.set_visible(True)
for _, spine in ax0.spines.items():
    spine.set_visible(True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seaborn, by default, sets the outline line width of the colour bar to zero<sup>[1](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/v0.11.1/seaborn/matrix.py#L309)</sup>.

You can set the line width (`lw`) and edge colour for all the spines in each `ax` like so:

```py
fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
sns.heatmap(df, annot=False, cmap="RdYlGn", cbar_ax=ax1, ax=ax0)

for spine in ax0.spines.values():
    spine.set_visible(True)
for spine in ax1.spines.values():
    spine.set(visible=True, lw=.8, edgecolor="black")
```

Which produces:

[image]

The colour bar also has an `outline` spine so `ax1` could just be done with just this line.

```py
ax1.spines["outline"].set(visible=True, lw=.8, edgecolor="black")
```

Comment: Thanks Alex!
I ran your code on Spyder but it shows no change as compared to mine. Do you know the reason? The second part of your code brings an error: "KeyError: 'outline' "

Comment: Do you know what version of matplotlib/seaborn you are using?

Comment: Matplotlib 3.3.4   and   Seaborn 0.11.0

Comment: Can you try increasing the `lw` to something like 5? See if they are too thin to render?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Even when I change between ax0 and ax1, the heatmap always has the contour while the colorbar is without it. How does it work for you?

Comment: In [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5p9B.png) I have increased the colour bar line width to 5. Is that the border you are expecting to be visible?

Comment: It seems to work in your code, but not in mine. Strange :/

Comment: What matplotlib backend are you using? Try running: `import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.get_backend())`

Comment: module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline

Comment: Are you using `%matplotlib inline`? Maybe try switching to something like `matplotlib.use('Agg')` after importing matplotlilb?

Comment: I'm working on Spyder, not Jupyter notebook. Anyway, I tried it - didn't help. I think we can finish the discussion. Thanks for your attention