# Shrink and anchor matplotlib colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, colorbar

How do I use colorbar attributes such as in this snippet:

```
import seaborn as sns

uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12) # random data
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data)

cbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar

plt.show()
```

To shrink the colorbar and put it to the bottom and anchored to the lower left corner (that is, NOT centered)?

Something like this, but with the colorbar shrunk to, let's say 70% and anchored to the bottom left

[image]

I am unsure how to search for the methods as `cbar.set_location()` is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the colorbar via seaborn, extract its position, adapt it and set it again:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data, cmap='rocket_r', cbar_kws={'orientation': 'horizontal', 'ticks': np.linspace(0, 1, 6)})

cax = ax.collections[0].colorbar.ax  # get the ax of the colorbar
pos = cax.get_position()  # get the original position
cax.set_position([pos.x0, pos.y0, pos.width * 0.6, pos.height])  # set a new position
cax.set_frame_on(True)
cax.invert_xaxis()  # invert the direction of the colorbar
for spine in cax.spines.values():  # show the colorbar frame again
     spine.set(visible=True, lw=.8, edgecolor='black')
plt.show()
```

[image: change seaborn colorbar position]

Note that you need `cbar_kws={'orientation': 'horizontal'}` for a horizontal colorbar that by default is aligned with the x-axis.

After using `.set_position`, something like `plt.tight_layout()` won't work anymore.

About your new questions:

- `cax.invert_xaxis()` doesn't invert the colorbar direction

  - Yes it does. You seem to want to reverse the colormap. Matplotlib's convention is to append `_r` to the colormap name. In this case, seaborn is using the `rocket` colormap, `rocket_r` would be the reverse.  Note that changing the ticks doesn't work the way you try it, as these are just numeric positions which will be sorted before they are applied.
  - If you want to show `0` and `1` in the colorbar (while the values in the heatmap are e.g. between `0.001` and `0.999`, you could use `vmin` and `vmax`.  E.g. `sns.heatmap(..., vmin=0, vmax=1)`.  `vmin` and `vmax` are one way to change the mapping between the values and the colors.  By default, `vmin=data.min()` and `vmax=data.max()`.
- To show the colorbar outline: [Add a black frame around a colorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68297160/add-a-black-frame-around-a-colorbar)
- `ax.collections[0].colorbar` is a [colorbar](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/colorbar_api.html#matplotlib.colorbar.Colorbar), which in the latest versions also supports some functions to set ticks
- `ax.collections[0].colorbar.ax` is an [`Axes object`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html#the-axes-class) (a subplot). Matplotlib creates a small subplot on which the colorbar will be drawn. `ax`s support a huge number of functions to change how the subplot looks or to add new elements.  Note that a stackoverflow answer isn't meant to put of full matplotlib tutorial.  The [standard tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/index.html) could be a starting point.

Comment: Thanks! However, `cax.invert_xaxis()` doesn't invert the colorbar direction. I should probably mention that colorbar ticks are set through `cbar_kws=dict(ticks=np.round(np.linspace(0, 1, 6),1)`. Using `np.linspace(1,0, 6)` doesn't fix the issue. Also, how to I make the colorbar frame visible? `.outline.set_linewidth(1)` is not appropriate anymore

Comment: I added a frame with `cax.set_frame_on(True)`. Can I just reset the ticks of the colorbar to invert it?

Comment: It looks like I can `ax.collections[0].colorbar.set_ticklabels(np.round(np.linspace(1,0, 6),1) )`. Any links to learn about the difference between `ax.collections[0].colorbar` and `ax.collections[0].colorbar.ax` and their methods will be enormously appreciated! Also, how can I put a label/title to the horizontal colorbar ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want infinite customizability, you need to go more low level than you will get with seaborn, which gives convenience, but can't have knobs for everything.

The most straightforward way to get what you want is to place the colorbar axes manually.  Note that you will need to play with the y offset, which I set here to -0.2.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12) # random data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(layout='constrained')
pc = ax.imshow(uniform_data)
cbax = ax.inset_axes([0, -0.2, 0.7, 0.05], transform=ax.transAxes)
fig.colorbar(pc, ax=ax, cax=cbax, shrink=0.7, orientation='horizontal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I know what you mean, but I specifically need to work that out through seaborn and `ax.collections[0].colorbar` as I am editing a code that is not mine and has hundreds of lines, so it is inconvenient to reset the colorbar axes (inconvenient to me at least).

Comment: Seaborn takes both an ax argument and a cbar_ax argument.  Just pass the ax and cax above to them.

Comment: what do you need `transform=ax.transAxes` for? How do I "reverse" the colorbar (as it results now, it's with `1` to the left and `0` to the right)? But otherwise looks good!

Comment: You don’t really need the transAxes, it’s the default, but I always forget what the default is.  https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.inset_axes.html

Comment: Thanks. How about the reversed colorbar values? It was previously fixed by `plt.gcf().axes[1].invert_xaxis()` but now this gives error: `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Reversing the colorbar valued is a different question.